# How to prevent command line return string from printing

Tags: python

Basically, I'm sending a command like so:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ls",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmpStr = proc.stdout.read()
```

This works fine, but it also prints tmpStr to the screen, which I don't want. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I tried this same code here, but it didn't print anything, unless I call 'print tmpStr' directly...

Comment: I have the same experience as @JRicardo000. Is this exact example you're using? What platform are you using? Is it possible whatever command you're actually running is printing something to stderr, rather than stdout?

Comment: As @dano mentions, you are capturing stdout but not stderr. So, you'll still see error messages like "No such file or directory". Your example is very unlikely to error... but generally you'd want to include `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` or something like that.

Comment: When you observe this behavior, are you doing so from a python prompt? If you put the commands in a file and run the file, do you still see the output?

Comment: Are you seeing it like this: `>>> proc.stdout.read()` and then its printing the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably only printing because you are running the command by typing it at an interactive prompt. If you put that code in a file and execute it, tmpStr will not be printed out.

Comment: Good guess, but if its that _exact_ command, it won't print in the REPL either, since the last statement assigns the result.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: you could be right. My guess is, he's running this in some non-obvious shell that prints the results of each command as it's run.

Comment: @AndiJay: we've all been there at some point in our career, don't sweat it.